# Describe the probability space of the experience : "We throw two coins. If we get (Head,Head), we throw the two coins again".

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Describe the probability space $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ of the experience : "We throw two coins. If we get (Head,Head), we throw the two coins again".

I would say :

$$\Omega =\{(H,T),(T,H),(T,T),(H,H,H,H),(H,H,T,H),(H,H,H,T),(H,H,T,T)\}$$

$$\mathcal F=2^\Omega $$

and $$\mathbb P\{(\omega _1,\omega _2)\}=\frac{1}{4}$$ if $(\omega _1,\omega _2)\in\{(T,H),(H,T),(H,H)\}$ and $$\mathbb P\{(\omega _1,\omega _2,\omega _3,\omega _4)\}=\frac{1}{16}$$ if $(\omega _1,...,\omega _4)\in \{(H,H,H,H),(H,H,T,T),(H,H,T,H),(H,H,H,T)\}$.

---

**Question : Is it right ? I have in fact doubt for $\mathcal F$ because for example $\{(H,T),(H,H,H,H)\}$ cannot happen, so it should be something else, but I don't see how to describe it properly.**

Comment: That looks just fine to me for $\;\Omega\;$ .

Comment: What happens if at the second time again you throw H twice? Do you stop or do you throw again? Btw, in your title it is T twice. Confusing.

Comment: $\{(H,T),(H,H,H,H)\}$ can happen. It is the event that you throw $(H,T)$ **or** $(H,H,H,H)$.

Comment: @drhab: Thank you, I correct it. If at the second time we get (H,H) we stop anyway. So $\mathcal F=2^\Omega $ correct ? It looks strange because I saw that for conditional probability, the tribute may not be the same.

Comment: If $\omega\in\{(T,H),(H,T),(T,T)\}$ then $P(\{\omega\})=\frac14$ (so not $(H,H)$ as you wrote, but $(T,T)$). Further it is okay. I do not really understand your objection concerning conditional probability.